# Dimension formula/algorithm for quiver varieties?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-geometry, quiver, geometric-invariant-theory

The title says the question. For a quiver and a dimension vector and a stability vector, we can construct a moduli space of semistable quiver representations with the given dimension vector. The question is about the dimension of this moduli space. We can consider over $\mathbb{C}$.

A quick search discovers nothing relevant. I reckon this an open problem for a general quiver and dimension vector. So I also want to know anything results for special quivers.

Comment: You will likely be interested in chapter 10 of Kirillov's book [Quiver Representations and Quiver Varieties](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-174). In particular, theorem $10.8$ gives a calculation of the dimension of a quiver variety in terms of the euler form for the quiver.